# Changed HashRouter to BrowserRouter - Navbar no longer works, but links do

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I decided I need to stop using HasRouter, and instead, use BrowserRouter.

I switched out all my imports from:

```
import { HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

to

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

As well as all my blocks:

```
<HashRouter>
```

to

```
<BrowserRouter>
```

My app nearly behaved as expected. All links in my app work fine.

For example:

```
<Link to={{pathname: `/budget/${item.id}`, state: params}}>{item.name}</Link>
```

Updated my URL as expected and navigates to the component.

My history works too:

```
 handleEditRow(paymentNumber) {
        this.props.history.push(`/schedule/${this.state.scheduleId}/event/${paymentNumber}`);
    }
```

However, all my NavBar buttons fail. The URL updates as expected, but my app does not load the component:

I have my routes in :

```
  return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/accounts" component={Accounts} />
           ....
        </Switch>
        )
   }
```

I'm assuming this works, as the links above are behaving.

In my NavBar, I just do simple links:

```
<Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/accounts' exact>Accounts</Nav.Link>
```

I found a link that mentioned to use 'Link' instead of NavLink.

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to='/accounts' exact>Accounts</Nav.Link>
```

But this still fails. URL updates, but page doesn't change.

As I say, the URL changes as expected, but the app does not load the app.

However, if I then select the URL in the address bar, and press Enter (Load the URL that it changed to), the app loads the correct component, as expected.

Can anyone spot my error?

It was working fine with HashRouter.

Comment: Maybe you need to add <Switch> inside the <BrowserRouter>.

Comment: Tried that. It didn't need it before. I'm thinking it's a Nav.Link issue.

Comment: And no errors/warning in the console?

Comment: Just checked. Console reports noting. I have a lot of console.log (As I'm learning as I go) but nothing happens. I'm doing something wrong. I use React.Context - and my header is outside of the context group. It shouldn't matter though.

Comment: I found the issue.... I had two 'BrowserRouter'. One at a higher level - and one covering the main app area. It seems one was over-riding the other. The app should only have one 'BrowserRouter', I just learnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick tip: if you're not sure about which Router to use, you can import it aliased as "Router". You then don't have to change all HashRouter references to BrowserRouter if you decide to switch to another Router:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And then use:

```
<Router>
```

The advantage of this approach is that you only change the import and it works straight out of the box.